# How to access different variables in different subs?

Tags: input, integer, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to make a calculator on Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I've been trying to create different buttons, one asking for first number, second asking for second number, third asking for the operator and the last one displaying the answer in a message box. But whenever I try calling an Integer from another sub, it just doesn't work. I've tried making the sub Public. Here is my code :

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim prompt1, title1 As String
        Dim a As Integer
        prompt1 = "Enter First Number : "
        title1 = "First Number"
        a = InputBox(prompt1, title1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim prompt2, title2 As String
        Dim b As Integer
        prompt2 = "Enter Second Number : "
        title2 = "Second Number"
        b = InputBox(prompt2, title2)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim prompt3, title3 As String
        Dim op As String
        Dim ans As Integer
        prompt3 = "Enter Operator : "
        title3 = "Operator"
        op = InputBox(prompt3, title3)
        If op = "+" Then
            ans = a + 
        End If


    End Sub

    Public Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click


    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see I've not completed it because I can't call a in the third button.

Any ideas ?

If I'm messing up, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

define variable a outside of button1

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim a As Integer
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 Dim prompt1, title1 As String
 prompt1 = "Enter First Number : "
 title1 = "First Number"
 a = InputBox(prompt1, title1)
End Sub
```

Now you can use variable 'a'